# Master out of sync with remote with stashed files (one user only)

Tags: git

While "playing" with git, one of our users got into this situation:

[image]

I can't reproduce it unless I start messing with history (rebase).

He was the only one pushing to the remote.

Using stash, I can reproduce the "WIP on master:" and "Index on master" part, but I don't understand how master can be at that level, un-related to the remote...

Comment: For me it looks like the following: From the point of `remotes/master` someone played with some files and stashed them. (index on master). Later he poped the stash and master is one commit ahead `remotes/master`

Comment: master is not simply one commit ahead: it's on a different path. User can't even push, he has to pull first!

Answer (score 0):

> but I don't understand how master can be at that level, un-related to the remote...

It is related to the remote in that it has a common ancestor 'tt'.

But:

- a `git fetch` was done (hence the new commit in remotes/xxx/master)
- a `git stash` was done on master, stasjing intermediate changing not yet committed

So both histories diverge from '`tt`'.